# Использование функций других контроллеров

Tags: swift

У меня есть  VC1, в нем функция которая использует функцию из VC2

```
    class VC1: UIViewController {
    controllerVC2: VC2?
    func func1() {
    controllerVC2 = VC2()
    controllerVC2.controllerVC1 = self
    controller.printOk()
    }

    }

    class VC2: UIViewController {
    controllerVC1: VC1?
    func printOk() {
    print("ok")
    }
    }
class VC3: UIViewController {
controllerVC1: VC1?
func func() {
    controllerVC1 = VC1()
    controllerVC1.controllerVC1 = self
    controllerVC1.func1()
}
}
```

, но когда я из VC3 вызываю функцию func1 ничего не работает

Comment: Хм, а где тут VC3?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не создали элемент класса VC3

```
VC3().func() // создаем VC3()
```

или так

```
let vc3 = VC3()
vc3.func()
```